# When Does a Player's Turn End

Tags: ticket-to-ride

We had an issue come up tonight playing TtR.  Nearing the end of the game one player claimed a route, including placing the trains and turning in the train cards, leaving that player with only 5 trains left.  That player still needed to claim a 6 train route.  Realizing the mistake, the player immediately called for a change in which route he was claiming.  This happened BEFORE the next player did anything with their turn.  Player in question feels the next player did not start their turn, so it was still his turn and could change his mind.  Two other players in the game felt the player's turn ended when he placed his trains and turned in the cards.  The player in question lost.  There is nothing in the rules.  In Monopoly, it is still your turn until the next player rolls the dice.  Since there is no clear movement like this, when does a player's turn end in Ticket to Ride?

Answer (score 7):

As far as the game is concerned, you have ended your turn and the next player has been instructed to take theirs.<sup>[1]</sup> And since the rules say take-backsies are only allowed if... Wait a sec, there are no rules concerning take-backsies in Ticket to Ride. In fact, I've never see a game that allows take-backsies.

It doesn't mean you can't take back the move, but how that works is something your group will have to decide. Personally, I have absolutely no problem with allowing the change since nothing was done based on the move that was performed. But this is my *opinion*. What your group allows/tolerates is up your group's business.

---

1. One of the expansions has an optional second action you can take. So, in that game, you may not have ended your turn.

Comment: absolutely.   I don't think any rules would ever specify exactly.   my personal opinion for all games would just be 'be nice'. if someone makes a mistake and no undoable event (like dice rolling or revealing a card) has happened then let a player take something back and keep the game fun rather than a punishing "must win at all costs" experience.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback.  It was a bit shocking to see the family turn on each other, but perhaps it was just because the player in question was in the lead and had the best chance to win.  Ticket-to-Ride is still a fun game to play.

Comment: If you force people to be 100% sure of their moves before doing them, the game will drag. It's generally a nicer experience for all if you allow take-backs if no further actions have been taken.